# How to hide javascript,web framework version details from weppalyzer

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, security, testing

For security reasons, we want to hide all js and bootstrap details. I use weppalyzer tool this show.
[image]

how to hide these details.
i also use exopose_php=off in php.ini file but it not work

Comment: How is the PHP ini file related? Or do you mean your PHP code is shown on the "view source" page/dev tools?

Comment: @Teemu It hides a header `X-Powered-By: PHP/5.3.7` so yes this is **also** relevant.

Comment: Security through obscurity is not security.

Comment: You can't. Maybe you can a little bit, but you can't hide it from people are determined.Your manager is worried that competitors will find out his competitive secret that he uses jQuery in your app? Tell him that's not how things work.

Comment: It's going to be *very* hard to hide that you're using Bootstrap, and you'd receive **zero** security benefit by hiding that.

Comment: *"For security reasons"* - I don't think that means what you and/or your employer think it means.  What *specifically* are you trying to prevent here?  If a user can break your security simply by knowing you use jQuery then your security is *seriously flawed*.  Hiding jQuery from the user doesn't correct those flaws.

Answer (score 4):

You might, with a lot of work, be able to hide that you're using Laravel and Apache, but the client-side stuff is going to be next to impossible to mask from a determined technically-minded user.

Any security benefit you gain here will be illusory. You'll find potential attackers already probe your site for common frameworks and vulnerabilities using automated scripts - if you look at your webserver logs, you'll see all sorts of failed requests for `/phpmyadmin/`, `/wp-admin/`, etc. in them.

Keep your stuff updated and patched and worry about your code rather than these heavily used and well vetted frameworks.

Answer (score 1):

You should look at the [source code](https://github.com/AliasIO/Wappalyzer/blob/master/src/apps.json)  where you can see what variable is used to determine this information.

```
"Laravel": {
  "cats": [
    18
  ],
  "cookies": {
    "laravel_session": ""
  },
  "icon": "Laravel.png",
  "implies": "PHP",
  "website": "http://laravel.com"
}
```

As you can see, the cookie name `laravel_session` is used. change it in config/session.php in your project. You also might notice Laravel implies PHP, so even if you can hide all traces of PHP, just a Laravel cookie is enough to extrapolate that PHP is also used.